# Configurable Products - showing customer total prices in dropdown options instead of +/- pricing

Tags: configurable-product, products, price

Can anyone please help. I have Magento Community 1.7 installed and can't find any way to change how the pricing is displayed for Configurable products.

I want to show the total price and not have +£10 etc on the different configuration options.

Is there any simple and effective way to do this please? I've tried the Magento Exchange Configurable Products addon which broke my store...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is performed by javascript. From [here](http://dltr.org/blog/magento/258/Magento-show-actual-price-on-product-options-for-configurable-products) i got this code:

```
// BEGIN:: custom price display update
var basePrice = parseFloat(this.config.basePrice);
// 'price' as passed is the RELATIVE DIFFERENCE. We won't use it.
//  The ABSOLUTE DIFFERENCE is in option.price (and option.oldPrice)
var absoluteDifference = parseFloat(option.price);
// var price = parseFloat(price);
if(absoluteDifference){
    // console.log(option);
    price = basePrice + absoluteDifference;
} else {
    price = absoluteDifference;
}
// END:: custom price display update
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225093/replace-price-difference-with-actual-price-in-magento-configurable-product-optio) is another question with an answer too.

Comment: Hi thanks but I believe this is different in 1.7 which is what I'm running. Can anyone verify if it will still work as the above was used on 1.5? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can verify that yourself.

Comment: Hi yes I can verify that this doesn't work for 1.7 community edition. Does anyone know another way to achieve this?